# Can Apache Tiles be used on an offline application?

Tags: spring, tiles, offlineapps

I'm currently developping a Java app using SpringBoot & Maven.
I'm thinking of using the Apache Tiles framework in order to compose my JSP.
Here's the problem: in the future, this app will have an offline mode.
So: Does Tiles is implementing well within an app in offline mode ?

Thx !

**EDIT**
I do make requests to a back-end service. I was using JSP until now, wich worked fine, but I wanted to learned more about Tiles.

Comment: "Offline" in what sense? I mean, if you're not making any requests to a back-end, sure.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I sould have been clearer. I do make requests to a back-end service. Until now, I was using JSP, wich worked fine. But I learned about Tiles, and wanted to practice it a bit :)

Comment: If it works with JSP, it'll work with Tiles.

Comment: Thanks, my mind is clearer now :) 
I've validated the other one, because of the details of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, Apache Tiles is just a piece of software that compiles your view from various different sources, which at the end of the day results in a simple HTML document.  As I am sure you are aware, you don't need to be "on-line" to use HTML!

You would only incur a problem if your application accesses other services over the internet, like a database etc...  But thats not Apache Tiles, that just how you've made your application!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll start working on it right away! :)